# GWT - convert string to float 2 decimal places

Tags: java, gwt

I have some string values that I need to convert to float while preserving two decimal places. I am using GWT so all the examples I try dont work in GWT 2.7

```
String value = "00.00";
String value2 = "-34.90";
String value3 = "3.45";
```

How can I convert string to float with 2 decimal places in GWT?

Comment: Are you asking "how to convert a String to a float?" or "why are the converted floats not the exact same value as the Strings?"

Comment: `float` and `double` doesn't store a specific count of decimal places. They store *numbers*, and `-34.9` is the same *number* as `-34.90`. If you *need* the number to remember the exact count of decimal places, then you need to use a `BigDecimal`, not a `float`. Usually, number don't need to remember the count of decimal places. You simply *format* the number to two decimal places when printing it.

Answer (score 1):

GWT is a framework and you don't "convert" strings to floats in GWT but in Java.

As already stated in comments, you can't ask for a specific precision in *float* or *double*. You also can't trust that their `String` representation is their actual value...

If you really need only two decimals to represent a number, I suggest you use an `int` that gets the value times 100, then perform the simple arithmetics anywhere you need. You can wrap it in a [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class:

```
class TwoDecimal extends Number {
    protected int val;

    public TwoDecimal(double val) {
        this.val = (int)Math.round(100 * val);
    }

    @Override
    public double toDouble() {
        return val / 100.0;
    }

    // Implement other abstract toXXX() methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (val / 100) + "." + (val % 100);
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind that an `int` might not be able to store the span a `double` covers, so you should adapt it to your use-case.